# Выборы модератора сообщества 2019

Tags: обсуждение, выборы

В настоящее время проводятся выборы модераторов сообщества 2019!

Выборы модераторов сообщества состоят из трёх этапов:

1. Выдвижение кандидатур.
2. Предварительные выборы.
3. Выборы.

Обычно процесс выборов занимает от 2 до 3 недель, но всё зависит от количества кандидатов.

Пожалуйста, посетите [официальную страницу выборов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election) для получения дополнительной информации и принимайте участие!

Если у вас есть вопросы по процессу проведения выборов или по кандидатам в модераторы, задавайте их здесь, на Мете — только убедитесь, что ваши вопросы имеют метку [выборы](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b).