# С какой целью объявлены выборы?

Tags: обсуждение, выборы

Как известно, срок действия модераторов на Stack Exchange не ограничен и поэтому выборы проводятся не регулярно, а объявляются только когда для этого есть причины. Например, если имеющиеся модераторы не справляются с задачами либо один или несколько модераторв решили сложить с себя полномочия.

Я искал информацию по этому поводу в [чате сообщества](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--), но нашел только спекуляции. Причина проведения выборов также не освещена ни на [странице выборов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/3), ни в [официальном объявлении на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9119/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-2019). Существенного ажиотажа в очередях проверки я в последнее время не наблюдал, т.ч. очевидного повода для выборов я со своей невысокой колокольни не вижу.

Полагаю, что цель проведения выборов будет полезно услышать как кандидатам (будут знать какие задачи будут перед ними поставлены), так и избирателям (будут иметь больше информации для голосования).

Сейчас (последние два года) у нас есть [пять модераторов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) плюс сотрудник компании @NicolasChabanovsky. Хотелось бы чтобы кто-нибудь из них рассказал сообществу что послужило поводом для проведения выборов 2019.

Comment: `Например, если имеющиеся модераторы не справляются с задачами либо один или несколько модераторв решили сложить с себя полномочия` есть мнение, что слагать полномочия нужно только, если их действия вредят. По-моему про это Ник писал в своё время в треде про Бармалея.

Comment: @Suvitruf В сети есть прецеденты добровольного отказа от должности. Например, [Bill the Lizard на en.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291036/451518)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Причина очень проста - не хватает модераторов :)

У нас их 5, но это достаточно мало - [в португальском разделе сейчас 6 модераторов](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), при том, что у них почти в два раза меньше вопросов в день. На SuperUser, который чуть активнее ruSO - [9 ромбов](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday).

Кто-то из текущих модераторов стал менее активен, кто-то завален работой и ушел в мод отпуск, кто-то просто устал. Это никак не связано с состоянием очередей проверок или какими-то конфликтами - просто среди модераторов тоже есть выгорание и текучка.

Если модераторов не добрать, то через год-полтора сайт будет активно модерировать один человек. В лучшем случае - два. Существующие модераторы собрались, обсудили, и решили, что стоит добрать еще людей заранее, до того, как сайт охватит анархия :)

NicolasChabanovsky, кстати, не модератор, и непосредственно модерированием почти не занимается - он курирует ruSO примерно настолько, насколько и другие международные сообщества.

Comment: Просто ещё месяц назад говорили, что модераторы не нужны, а текущие справляются. Что поменялось-то =/?

Comment: @Suvitruf посмотрели внимательно на статистику модерирования и передумали. бывает.

Comment: @Suvitruf, ЮрийСПБ не вывозит :-D

Comment: @Grundy высылаем помощь )

Comment: @Grundy, не правда) Но да, помощь не помешает)