# Будут ли в этом году выборы модераторов на ru.SO?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация

Будут ли в этом году выборы модераторов на ru.SO ?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [С какой целью объявлены выборы?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9136/С-какой-целью-объявлены-выборы)

Comment: @Suvitruf - Andrei Apanasik Вы кстати не знаете?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica есть вероятность, что будут.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, и есть вероятность что не будут :-D

Comment: Я согласен с @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik что есть вероятность что будут. Подписывайтесь на наш канал, ставьте лайки.

Comment: Что характерно, никто не рискнул сделать более сильное утверждение - что эта вероятность ненулевая. :)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398884/2020-moderator-election-qa-question-collection?cb=1